# Отключение @everyone и @here в команде say. discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Мне необходимо отключить пинги @everyone и @here в команде say.

мой код:

```
let botmessage = args.join(" ");
  message.delete().catch();
  message.channel.send(botmessage);
} catch (err) {
  return message.reply(`Ошибочка, сообщите пожалуйста: AnimeFlame#6666 \`${err.message}\`.`);
}
```

Comment: Это в настройках ролей отключается, а не в боте.

Comment: А чем не устраивает вариант с вырезанием @ everyone и @ here из сообщений, либо же просто выдача ошибки пользователю из-за этого?